# La nueva barra superior se sobrepone a los snippets

Tags: bug, estado-completado, stack-snippets, barra-superior

La nueva barra de navegación se sobrepone a los snippets, escondiendo partes que pueden ser importantes para entender el problema o cómo funciona el código. Esto parece ser un bug, <strike>pero no sé si no se considera un error porque hay una opción para deshabilitar el "stickiness" de la barra</strike> Mariano ha confirmado en los comentarios que pasa aunque se deshabilite el stickiness/adhesividad de la barra.

Por ejemplo, he visto ese comportamiento incorrecto en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75246/250). Si se ejecuta el código dentro de la pregunta, se ven dos barras de menú, una negra y una naranja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que si le damos al botón de "Página completa", entonces sólo se ve una barra (la naranja) porque la otra (la negra) queda detrás de la navegación del sitio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mismo caso, incluso con la barra con "stickiness" deshabilitada/con movilizar barra, en Chrome 57 Android N

Comment: Por cierto, @Mariano, ¿etiquetamos esta pregunta con [meta-tag:barra-superior] o [meta-tag:barra-de-navegación]?

Comment: @fedorqui editado (pregunta y wikis de etiqueta)

Comment: Justo iba a realizar yo esta pregunta también. Mismo comportamiento en esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75437/problemas-con-el-margin-de-un-menu#comment138734_75437 en la cual el menú queda por debajo de la barra de navegación.